# Using vectors in c++

Tags: c++, data-structures, vector

I have this piece of code but it gives me a lot of errors. I am not getting the reason behind it.

```
void coolingpie(int n)
{
int i=0,j;
while(i<n)
{
    int p;
    vector<int> pies[p], racks[p];      // p number of cooling pie
    cin>> p;                            //number of coiling pies or racks
    for(j=0;j<p;j++)
    {
        cin>>input;               //reading the weights of the p pies
        pies.push_back(input);
    }
    for(j=0;j<p;j++)
    {

        cin>>p;                // reading the maximum weights of the racks
        racks.push_back(input);
    }
    std::sort(pies.begin(), pies.end());
    std::sort(racks.begin(), racks.end());
    findthemaxpies( vector<int>& pies, vector<int>& racks);     
}
}
```

Comment: Make it `vector<int> pies, racks;`

Comment: What is this line supposed to do? `findthemaxpies( vector<int>& pies, vector<int>& racks);`

Comment: If you read into `p` in the same loop for which `p` is the upper bound, you are gonna have a bad time.

Comment: `vector<int> pies[p], racks[p];` You are misunderstanding what `vector` does.  A single `vector` can hold multiple values.  You are declaring an array of `vectors` with that line of code.  That certainly isn't correct.

Comment: Please be specific when specifying errors

Comment: You are using p before initializing it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, I'd wager it's supposed to do what `findthemaxpies(pies, racks);` does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things wrong with your program:

```
vector<int> pies[p], racks[p];
```

Should be:

```
vector<int> pies, racks;
```

The reason is that the first definition declares an `array` of `vector`.  That certainly can't be right, unless you really want to declare an array of vectors.  What you want to do is declare two vectors that start out with no elements, and that is what the second line does.

You then have this:

```
 findthemaxpies( vector<int>& pies, vector<int>& racks);
```

That line declares a function called `findthemaspies`.  It is legal, but does nothing.  If you want to *call* the function with those arguments, then it would be this:

```
 findthemaxpies( pies, racks);
```

You have another issue with your second loop:

```
  for(j=0;j<p;j++)
  {
        cin>>p;                // reading the maximum weights of the racks
        racks.push_back(input);
  }
```

You are using `p` in the loop condition, but changing `p` in the loop, as well as using `input` that never changes value.  That can't be right.  It probably should be something like this:

```
  int p2;
  for(int j=0; j<p; j++)
  {
     cin >> p2;                // reading the maximum weights of the racks
     racks.push_back(p2);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should always post the errors that you are receiving along with your code.

In your case, some of your errors may be originating from how you declared your vector. Drop the brackets and you should be fine (in that regard).

```
vector<int> pies;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 vector<int> pies[p], racks[p];      // p number of cooling pie
```

To

```
vector<int> pies(p), racks(p);      // p number of cooling pie
```

if pies is a class you can create a vector of pies

```
vector<pies> piesObject(p);
```